# Cache strategy for rails where new objects appearing invalidates the cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

I'm not seeing something obvious re:caching strategies in rails.

I have a prices table that logs prices at particular times. So the current price would be the last row added to the prices table. Very frequently, the table is queried to display the entries, so caching that fetching would be great to stop (very) frequent queries hitting the database.

So as far as I can see it would be fine for my entire app to cache that data completely *until a new row gets added*.

Does rails caching handle that well? I see examples for on update of an active record object you expire the cache and force the updated object to be retrieved again - but I want the collection of objects (e.g. Price.find(:all) to be cached until Price.find(:all) contains a new object. So adding a new row to the db would have to expire the cache and force a new retrieval - the new price might be the latest for a few days, or it might only last a few minutes.)

If not self-evident, this is the first time I've ever looked at caching. I'll be attempting to deploy memcache on heroku.

Thanks a lot!

**Edit**: Just thought it might be useful to point out that the rails controllers only render JSON requests - rich single page app - so the main things to cache are the database query. This is why it is confusing me, I see partial caching, page caching, but I'm struggling to understand the type of caching I'm hopefully describing above.

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cache your prices, you can use the following.  It would be helpful to place this somewhere it could be reused (such as your model).

```
cached_prices = Rails.cache.fetch("cached_prices", :expires_in => 300) do
    Price.find(:all)
end
```

The above code caches the query for 5 minutes (300 seconds).  In order to manually delete the cache entry (say when a new Price entry is created), call the following:

```
Rails.cache.delete("cached_prices")
```

To make this easier, you can place the cache delete code in an Observer on the Price model.

You can find much more information on all of the types of caching you have available to you here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: You can also learn about Observers here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html